# Deploy Helm Chart through Azure Devops Classic UI Release Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a yaml build pipeline in which I use HelmDeploy builtin azure devops task to package my helm chart and publish it in a specific folder.

This works fine and produces a tgz compressed folder with the k8s manifests.

However while trying to create a classic ui Release pipeline I can only find kubectl deploy or plain kubectl tasks which are not suitable to install my helm chart.

After searching the documentation I can only see mentions in yaml pipelines which HelmDeploy build in task is used to install the chart by providing the necessary cluster credentials.

Is this the only approach for helm deployment through azure devops ?

P.S : Right now I am using an additional task in the build pipeline `helm template` to convert the templates to k8s manifests and then use a kubectl apply task in the release pipeline to deploy those.

Comment: You used the kubernetes tag which states "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here."

Comment: The point is not the tag.  The point is the content of the question.  I pointed the tag out because it gives the general guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are able to use the `HelmDeploy` task in release pipelines. You may search for the `Package and deploy Helm Charts` task in the classic editor. See [HelmDeploy@0 - Package and deploy Helm charts v0 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/helm-deploy-v0?view=azure-pipelines) for more information.

[image]